# How to create expansion panels with MDC web?

Tags: components, material-design

They have it in their [List Documentation](https://material.io/components/lists/#types) and in their Design Guideline as ["Expansion Panels"](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/expansion-panels.html#) but not in their [List Demo](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/list).

[image]

Technically, this is what I want, but it's not specified how to get there and how to actually use it. My question is how and if this can be done. I have found multiple older [issues](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/3738) discussing this and my hope is that it just didn't make it into the docs yet.

For everybody who finds this and just wants a solution that's not necessarily material design:

- [How to create a collapsible?@W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible)
- style guide from [the official docs](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/expansion-panels.html#expansion-panels-behavior).  (you still have to implement these yourself)

Comment: It seems they're adding a Material Component, but for now devs are expected to figure it out themselves: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/5939#issuecomment-675067653

Comment: I am unable to find any news about this. Did you see anything?